# Assign a variable from a SQLite table entry

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I would like to be able to assign a variable from a SQLite table entry I have, I need to be able to get the QTY of the part_no which will be entered by the user. So the user enters a part number, it then searches the database for the part number, once found assigns a variable with the QTY from the qty column for the searched part.

My table set up is below...

```
db = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite3')
cursor = db.cursor()
# Table creation
cursor.execute('''
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS spares(
                id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                part_no TEXT,
                desc TEXT,
                qty NUM,
                rack TEXT,
                shelf TEXT)
                ''')
db.commit()
```

I'm unsure on how to write the SQL command to do this or if if can be done at all?

What I have done so far is the below, but this does not grab the qty which I need!

```
selection = askstring('Please enter your Part Number:)

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM spares WHERE part_no LIKE '%' || ? || '%'", (selection,))
```

The above returns the searched part number row, but now how do I set a variable with the QTY entry for that part number?

The reason for been able to do this is so I can do math on the qty to either + or - the entry.

Thanks in advance as always :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use UPDATE query. Insert this query into your `execute` function:

```
UPDATE spares SET qty = 'some qty' WHERE part_no LIKE '%' || ? || '%';
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this would be the execute query I would use to update the qty, but I first need the qty to do the math. This is why I need the qty to a variable first then do the above execution.

Comment: In that case, replace * with qty in your original query. This would give just the qty and not the entire table

Comment: Thanks, @mujeebur I think this will work I will try it and comment on the results.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I did the below...

```
def remove_data():
    spare_to_remove = askstring('Remove Spare', 'Please enter your part number you wish to remove')
    amount_taken = askstring('Amount Taken', 'Please enter the amount you wish to take')
    amount_taken = int(amount_taken)
    cursor.execute('''SELECT qty FROM spares WHERE part_no LIKE '%' || ? || '%' ''', (spare_to_remove,))
    q_t_y = cursor.fetchone()
    tup_to_int = int(''.join(map(str, q_t_y)))
    sum = (tup_to_int - amount_taken)
    cursor.execute('''UPDATE spares SET (qty) = (?) WHERE part_no = ?''', (sum, spare_to_remove,))
    db.commit()
    messagebox.showinfo('Removed Part', 'Adjusted QTY to ' + str(sum))
```

hope this helps anyone else with the same issue!